# How to stop recursion in a CTE?

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a database table which looks like this:

```
ID                                   | PredecessorID                        | Data
-------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|-----------------
43b1e103-d8c6-40f9-b031-e5d9ef18a739 | null                                 | ...
55f6951b-5ed3-46c8-9ad5-64e496cb521a | 43b1e103-d8c6-40f9-b031-e5d9ef18a739 | ...
3eaa0889-31a6-449d-a499-e4beb9e4cad1 | 55f6951b-5ed3-46c8-9ad5-64e496cb521a | ...
```

I know that I can use a (recursive) common table expression (CTE) to get a sorted list of my data:

```
WITH cte (ID, Data)
AS
(
  -- base case
  SELECT x.ID, x.Data
  FROM MyTable AS x
  WHERE x.PredecessorID IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  -- other cases
  SELECT x.ID, x.Data
  FROM MyTable as x
  INNER JOIN cte
    ON x.PredecessorID = cte.ID
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

While this works, if I want to get the entire table, I wonder how to only get a part of the table, say, everything between from ID `x` up to ID `y`.

Getting the lower bound right is easy (I assume): Simply change the `WHERE` criteria of the base case to the ID I want to start with:

```
  -- base case
  SELECT x.ID, x.Data
  FROM MyTable AS x
  WHERE x.PredecessorID='...'
```

But what about the upper bound? How do I tell the CTE to stop recursing once the record with the ID `y` has been reached?

Comment: What RDBMS ? Looks like either MS SQL Server or Oracle.

Comment: ANSI SQL 99 … so let's assume SQL Server or PostgreSQL (actually I need it to work in both).

Comment: You should add an extra condition to the anchor select (first) with " and ID between x and y". This shoukd help.

Comment: The problem is that the IDs are UUIDs, and hence I can't assume that they have any order that I can refer to with between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are iterating here and have the cte's last id that it picked up available in your recursive term you can just filter out results where the last iteration hit 'y'

```
WITH cte (ID, Data)
AS
(
  -- base case
  SELECT x.ID, x.Data
  FROM MyTable AS x
  WHERE x.PredecessorID IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  -- other cases
  SELECT x.ID, x.Data
  FROM MyTable as x
  INNER JOIN cte
    ON x.PredecessorID = cte.ID
  WHERE cte.id <> 'y'
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Note that if your `x` id has many branches, some of which don't lead to 'y' then those branches will keep iterating until they hit their natural end. Only branch leading to `y` will be prematurely stopped here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I assume this would work, but the `path` could not get longer than 2000 characters right? The data form a single linked list, so I don't have any branches at all, but there may be millions of records here. Will this still work?

Comment: If you have millions, then no... don't track path. Instead just track "Last encountered id" I will rewrite.

Comment: That's awesome! I'm completely new to CTEs (actually I only learned about them *today*), so I really appreciate your help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually... as I think about it, for your needs, you can just refer back to the last entry in `cte` that lead to the current iteration and kill the query if the cte.id = 'y'. Super easy. The `path` is super nice though if you have many legs. I also generally add a `depth` and increment + 1 each iteration so I can kill a query at so many iterations, or see how deep I had to go to get to the current iteration.

Comment: One other note on `path` (Again not used here, but useful) is that if your data child/parent should ever refer back to itself causing an endless loop you can check for that by querying your path in the where clause to see if you've been there before.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, it really helped me . Since I can upvote only once, I gave 250 points to you via a bounty. Hope you like it!

Comment: I appreciate it @GoloRoden! Some day I'm going to trade these fake internet points in for something nice. I'm really glad I was able to help out on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just curious if you could simply modify the recursive select part to stop when id becomes y (assuming that there is only 1 path from x to y), similar to this:

`with recursive cte (count) as (
  select 1 as count
  union all
  select count + 1 from cte where count != 100
)
select * from cte;`